# Does a ritual-summoned gargoyle get its own turn in a fight?

Tags: dnd-4e, rituals, summoning

I'm interested in exactly how the gargoyle from the summon gargoyle ritual<sup>[DDI](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/ritual.aspx?id=392)</sup> works. It allows a ritual caster to summon a gargoyle to guard an area or object, its type/strength depending on your arcana roll. However runic gargoyles protect the caster.

Let's say the caster summons a runic gargoyle to protect them in battle, an encounter occurs, and it is available in combat. Does it protect the caster by:

1. using an opportunity attack on adjacent enemies who attack the caster
2. being an instinctive creature instead allowing an action on it's turn the way a instinctive summon works
3. both (1) and (2)

Which one of these is how the runic gargoyle works? Many DMs have ruled in each of the different variates even in sanctioned games, and I want to know how it actually works.

Answer (score 3):

> The gargoyle attacks any creature that approaches the object or enters the area, though it allows for any exceptions you make. (*Dragon*, p. 423)

You're the object here, so it attacks anything that approaches it that you didn't provide as an exception.

It's option 2. The gargoyle is autonomous and has it's own actions. It does not consume yours. You are the gargoyle's master and thus powers that refer to "it's master" apply to you.

Comment: Then as another question attached to this one, depending on arcana roll i can summon stronger gargoyles, can i designate their protection area as a area around me even when im moving for example all clarified enemies, in burst 5 of me at all times? Allowing me to use the higher tier gargoyles in effectivly the same manner as the runic gargoyle? Also thank you for the quick reply

Comment: @Jeff If you have a new question, even if it's related, please post it as a new question using the Ask Question button. We can't properly answer a question left as a comment.